# How to avoid jQuery on() method bind twice?

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I want to trigger a customized job on window resize after certain data is loaded:

```
function doJob() { 
    ... 
}

DataLoaded() {
   $(window).on("resize", function() { doJob(); });
}
```

However `DataLoaded` can be occured multiple times, how can I make sure doJob() only bind once ?

> PLEASE NOTE, bind once, but can be executed multiple times, so $("...").one("...") is not my goal

IMO:

> 1. set a global variable `isBind` to check if method is bind, which looks redundant
> 2. $(window).off("resize").on("resize", ....), I'm not sure if calling off() first is a safe way

Comment: You want to call `doJob()` only once not multiple times ?

Comment: @M.Tanzil yes, it can be multiple times. I updated my question.

Comment: You could have done `$(window).resize(doJob);`

Comment: `$(window).off("resize.DataLoaded").on("resize.DataLoaded", function() { doJob(); });`

Comment: @ArunPJohny namespacing the event is a good choice

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks! I realized It could be most efficient way to achieve my goal.  Lots of basic rules were thrown away from my mind. :) Please post it as an answer

Comment: I deleted my answer.  `off` is the way to go, but I misunderstood the question.  But I don't understand why you're setting the `resize` event inside the `DataLoaded` function.  If you set it outside the function, it only gets bound once anyway, so you don't have to go to all this trouble.  Seems to me that that's the most efficient way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a flag variable like this:

```
var didJob = false;
DataLoaded() {
   $(window).on("resize", function() { 
     if(!didJob){
      doJob();
      didJob = true;
     }
   });
}
```

---

But I am not sure how you are calling DataLoaded function multiple times because inside this function you are also checking on window resize. So, it should not be called multiple times. Probably you want like this:

```
$(window).off("resize.DataLoaded").on("resize.DataLoaded", function() {
     doJob(); 
});
```

In the preceding example you see `resize.DataLoaded` and the `DataLoaded` is the [event namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/). Firstly you are unbinding resize event with DataLoaded namespace and then binding resize event with DataLoaded namespace so that it wouldn't affect any other resize event.

Answer (score 1):

You can unbind such event everytime you bind it

```
$(window).unbind("resize");
$(window).bind("resize", function() { doJob(); });
```

Comment: It's preferred to use `on()` and `off()`

Comment: @VinhNT If other plugins which have "window.resize" registered previously, does my unbind() call affect those bindings ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should do it like this, declare a variable and increment it after `doJob()` functions then do a check on it.

```
   function doJob() { 
        ... 
   }

   var once = 0;
   DataLoaded() {
    $(window).on("resize", function() { 
        if(once == 0){
          doJob();
          once++;
        }
    });
   }
```

Hope this helps.